# Title and meta tags of landing page are always shown irrespective of any URL entered in the tools like Semrush, Rankmath, Heymeta, Rankwatch

Tags: reactjs, seo, single-page-application, react-helmet

I have a website(single-page-application) built using ReactJs. Also I have used "react-helmet" to dynamically change title and meta tags of pages according to the URL and finally hosted over IIS. I can see on the browser the title and meta tags gets updated as per the URL request. But while I trying to validate the same in the SEO analyzer tools like Semrush, Rankmath, Heymeta, Rankwatch ect. the title always shows the title of landing page of website irrespective of URL I entered in these tools. Which may be same how search engines will also see my site.

I tried searching similar libraries like "react-helmet", but unfortunately couldn't find one. And few articles I read over internet where people mentioned because it's a SPA(single-page-application) hence always the above mentioned SEO analyzer tools only able to scan one page which is the landing page.

So, I am here posting this to know what exactly the root cause for this issue and if it's because of SPA then what changes I need to in my reactJS application so that above mentioned SEO analyzer tools can get different title and meta tags when they hit different URL.

Comment: those tools are not executing your JavaScript. They just look at the HTML and you're rendering it client side with JS. You need to use SSR, perhaps with a framework like Next.js.

Comment: @Undo You mean I need to redevelop whole website using Next.js or I can stay in ReactJs and use Next.js into that?

Comment: Next.js is React frameowork, there will be some migration pains especially with routing but it has and can be done.